# Streamcoders.MediaSuite.x86 example

Tags: rtsp

I've installed the Streamcoders.MediaSuite.x86 from NuGet but I can't find any example how to use it for RTSP protocol. Can anyone show me an example or tell me where I can find some documentation?

Thanks

Comment: On their main page http://streamcoders.com/ theres a button that says 'sample code'. You need to login to see it.

Comment: Already seen it, but if I click on 'sample code' button it told me "Please see SDK distribution for up-to-date sample code"

Comment: Did you try and download the SDK from their site (not the NuGet package)?

Comment: Yes, by downloading from the site I get some examples. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543861/streamcoders-mediasuite-x86-example